# How to use "Data-Driven Input Mask" QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, configuration

I have installed [Data-Driven Input Mask](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataDrivenInputMask/) plugin in QGIS and added necessary relationships between PostgreSql tables. But I don't find any changes in the UI. How to enable/configure this plugin functionality in the attribute edit form as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/bstroebl/DataDrivenInputMask/wiki/Widgets-for-n-2-m-Relations)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already installed the `Data-Driven Input Mask` plugin in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) then you will find it going in the `Vector > Data-driven Input Mask` menu:

[image: menu.png]

Be very carefull when you use this plugin because I've noticed that it can be very buggy.
You must to select and activate your *PostGIS* layer before you press `Initialize layer`

After that, in your database will be automatically created three tables (`dd_field`, `dd_tab` and `dd_table`).

There's not too much documentation yet, and it is useful to read even the sql commentaries:

[image]

Another place where to find additional information is the plugin installation folder:

[image]

Comment: I have a 1:m relationship in my PostgreSql. I like to show the main table as well as relational table attribute edit (like grid) when i execute the action showDdForm. What are the entries i have to add to dd_* tables?

Comment: I rather think this is more a question than a comment, so that I think it's better for you to ask a new question, with more details about what you've done already and where you got stuck. In this way you will get more exposure for your problem and most users will get a chance to respond.

Comment: Please find my new question http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/83960/7188