# How to handle PostgreSql 1:m relationship data by using “Data-Driven Input Mask” QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, relates

I have 1:m relationship tables in my PostgreSql. I like to show the main table attributes as well as the relational table attributes (like grid rows) in QGIS attribute-edit-form.

What are the entries i have to add to dd_* tables to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in QGIS 2.2 (still in development) there will be a new feature that will allow to manage 1:n relations in a very fancy way.

When you open a feature form with a relation, you will the feature attributes and the related atributes connected to it. In the following example the table "reaches" as a 1:n relation to a table "maintenances".

[image]

For more information of how will it work take a look into this [blog post](http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations) from [Matthias kuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is an excellent feature. Is this Relations Management working in current QGIS master?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: QGIS 2.1 Freeze has this feature!

Answer (score 4):

Another approach will be to show a PostGIS view in QGIS, using 'Instead of triggers' in Postgres for handling CRUD operations. Field widges on the view in QGIS, can ensure the correct input, when updating joined fields from QGIS.

Comment: It is handful for 1:1 relations. But i like to get 1:m relations. Thanks.